# How to increment a value for children of a div using GSAP and plain JS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment, gsap

I would like to increment the value of the y-position by 10 pixels using plain Javascript and GSAP. How would I go about this?

This is what I have tried:
Please check my codepen here:
https://codepen.io/dada78/pen/8730bb1cc24a57c8da205e3439a6ad3c

```
    <div id="txt1Holder">
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
      <div class="mask">GO WHERE</div>
    </div> 


    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.mask');
    var tl = new TimelineMax();


    for (i = 1; i < rows.length + 1; i++) 
    {
     tl.set(rows + i, {y:10});
    }
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. The main problem is that your `for` loop is a bit misformed. It should be something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  tl.set(rows[i], {y:i * 10});
}
```

### [Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/ba91c0f23705bfee5c295f0fcf7555bd)

P.S. You're much more likely to get a faster response over on [the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) than here :)

Comment: Thanks Zach! That is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. I updated my codepen with this, however my second question would be how to decrement all txt class occurrences by 10px. If you take a look at the codepen, only the first txt element positions at -10px while the following positions to -9, followed by -8 etc. What logic would I need to use in order for it to decrement by 10px so it goes txt(1) = -10px, txt(2) = -20px, txt(3) = -30px etc? Thank you!

Comment: Your logic is correct in the pen. 10px just isn't that much :) You might want a bigger height on `txt1Holder` (or remove its `overflow: hidden;`) so that you can see the text if it's further down the page.

Comment: Thanks Zach, I have reflected your revised loop in the codepen, but might not have been clear in regards to the decrementing part, where I would like to have the value decrease by 10px for the .txt elements (see screenshots above). Currently it only decreases by 1px. Thanks! @Zach

Comment: @user2163224 Please do not edit your question to change the nature of the question. If you need additional help you should start a new question. But as I said in the last comment, simply change the number to make it bigger. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure what you would like to achieve but feels like .staggerTo method would help you. It basically will go through all of your targeted elements and do whatever you like with them - one by one, or all at once

Here's simple demo
https://codepen.io/tastysites/pen/JgJgQp

```
.staggerTo(rows,1,{y:'-=10'},0.4)
// 0.4 is time between each animation
// you can also use '+=10' or '-=10' to add or subtract a value from current value
```

If you will need any help, feel free to ask - though I would need to know a bit more about the desired effect to do it.

Cheers